# Set up a build system to run a sublime text command

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have SideBarEnhancements and would like to bind `Ctrl+B` to "Open in browser" for html files.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170056/open-up-url-on-local-machine-sublime/59180905#59180905), it seems like the command for key binding is `side_bar_open_in_browser`, but I'm not sure what to put for my `.sublime-build` file for command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused about how the Sublime Text build system works. The `SideBarEnhancements` command `side_bar_open_in_browser` can not be used with the build system.

You can however configure a `.sublime-build` file so that when you are editing an `HTML` file in Sublime Text and you run the `build` command, then the `HTML` file is opened in a web browser.

To do this start by creating a file called `HTML.sublime-build` in your Sublime Text user packages directory. i.e. `CONFIG_PATH/Packages/User/HTML.sublime-build` with `CONFIG_PATH` being your Sublime Text [data directory](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/getting-started/basic-concepts.html#the-data-directory) (that's the same location as your settings file). If you use the tools menu, i.e. `Menu --> Tools --> Build System --> New Build System`, to create the `HTML.sublime-build` file then the user packages directory will be automatically selected when you save the file.

Copy the following `JSON` into the `HTML.sublime-build` file:

```js
// Replace the "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" 
// path with your web browser's launch command.

{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.html",
    "file_patterns": ["*.html"]
}
```

Replace `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` in the `"cmd"` line with the path to launch your web browser. Any web browser can be used and, depending on your OS and system `path`, you may or may not need to enter the full path to that web browser. If you use a Windows OS then you will probably need to use a full path with forward slashes or double (escaped) back slashes in it. e.g.

```js
// Both of these sytles of Windows paths should work.
"cmd": ["C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe", "$file"],
"cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"],
```

Once this has been configured, open an `HTML` file in Sublime Text - the file must exist on disk - and then press `Ctrl+B` to launch the 'build' (or click on `Menu --> Tools --> Build`). The `HTML` file should open in your web browser. If the browser already has a window open on your desktop then the `HTML` file will open in it much more quickly than if not.

Links to documentation about the Sublime Text Build System: [Official Docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) and [Community Docs](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/build-systems/).